# In C++ inheritance, how can the derived class disable some elements (data or functions) of the base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

For example, suppose now we have two classes, Tree (base class) and BinaryTree (derived class). The class Tree have the data children and function getChildren().

```
class Tree {
public:
    vector<int> getChildren();
    ...
private:
    vector<int> children;
    ...
};
```

And the derived class have the data leftChild and rightChild, and functions of getLeftChild() and getRightChild().

```
class BinaryTree : public Tree {
public:
    int getLeftChild();
    int getRightChild();
    ...
private:
    int leftChild;
    int rightChild;
    ...
};
```

Definitely, the data children and function getChildren() is not what we want in the derived class. We may simply don't use them but they still exist. So how to disable these elements in the derived class?

Thanks

Comment: If a member function of a base class doesn't belong in the derived class, then perhaps the problem is that there isn't a subtype relationship between them?

Comment: First of all, why do you want to do that ? This would violate the [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), and may wreck polymorphism (what is someone want to act on a `BinaryTree` through a polymorphic reference to `Tree` ?). If you're just looking to reuse code, use private inheritance or composition as Jasper suggests. Otherwise, the problematic method has nothing to do in the superclass if it doesn't apply to every and all subclasses.

Comment: I think keeping them is a better idea. Disabling them kind of violates the whole idea of inheritance.

Comment: Only use inheritance, if there is an "is-a" relationship, that is if `BinaryTree` is a `Tree`. Simplified: If passed to a function, which takes `Tree` as argument and then calls `getChildren()`, it must work (or if it doesn't, then don't use inheritance).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem you're facing is about concepts, not programming.

In a `Tree` you get the children by calling `getChildren()`, and you could use the same for a `BinaryTree` the difference is that `BinaryTree::getChildren` will just return two children, the right, and the left.

If a `BinaryTree` is a (specialized) `Tree` is perfectly ok that you have a specialized version of `GetChildren`.

If you don't want base class members to exists in derived classes make them privates, if you want them to be public then you must consider use **composition instead inheritance**.

Answer (score 4):

In C++11 you can set `getChildren()` as deleted in the derived class:

```
vector<int> getChildren() =delete;
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using public tree, you can say `class BinaryTree:protected` Tree or `class BinaryTree:private` Tree. Alternatively, you can  include Tree as a data member in Binary Tree

For example:

```
class BinaryTree {
public:
    int getLeftChild();
    int getRightChild();
    ...
private:
   Tree tree;
    int leftChild;
    int rightChild;
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot "disable" members, but you can make any member private in an inherited class:

```
class A {
public:
 int x;
};

class B : public A {
private:
 using A::x;
};

B b;
b.x; // error - member x is not accessible
```

so outside of the class B the users of it will not be able (at least by mistake) to access `x`.

Answer (score -1):

```
pivate:   
vector<int> children;
vector<int> getChildren();
```

This private scope will not be available in the derived class.

Comment: It won't be available to anyone at all, making it completely useless.